# Checkbox added programmatically not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I add checkboxes that way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CheckBox FieldCh = new CheckBox();
        FieldCh.ID = "Field_" + Field.Id;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(FieldCh);
    }
}
```

but when I try to get this checkboxes from form:

```
foreach (Control item in FindControl("FieldForm").Controls)
  {
   if (item is Panel)
    {
      foreach (Control checkbox in item.Controls)
```

i cannot find this checkboxes :/ This could be problem with runat=server? I not find this property in Checkbox ..

Comment: From which function are you adding the controls?

Comment: When do you try to get this checkboxes? After postback? In which function/event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find this CheckBox after PostBack (what I've assumed), you need to recreate it. Try to create this CheckBox out of `if(!PostBack)` clause (so it's recreated after postback too):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox FieldCh = new CheckBox();
    FieldCh.ID = "Field_" + Field.Id;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(FieldCh);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         // ....        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. HTTP is stateless so unless you re-created the control on every postback or store it in the ViewState, you cannot access the control after the initial Page_Load because it does not exist!

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use `Page_Load` even to add controls dynamically.

```
protected void page_load()
{
CheckBox FieldCh = new CheckBox();
FieldCh.ID = "Field_" + Field.Id;
Panel1.Controls.Add(FieldCh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may simply use a better method of finding your control

just use this

```
CheckBox chkBox = this.form1.FindControl("YourControlId") as CheckBox;
```